# transform single element to Iterable in Java

Tags: java, c#, iterable, enumerable

In C#, I can transform a single element to an `IEnumerable<>` like this (using an extension method here):

```
static class Extensions
{
    static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T t)
    {
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

I use this when I need to input an `IEnumerable<>` somewhere but only have a single element, like here:

```
var myList = new List<string>("foo".Yield());
```

**Is there some equivalent way to do this in Java?**

I am NOT interested in actually creating an `Iterable<>` on the heap from an element like

```
List<String> myIterable = new ArrayList<String>();
myIterable.add("foo");
```

because I already know that kind of solution; I want to know if Java can handle enumerables/iterables as powerfully as C# (C# has Linq and yield return, Java has Streams) and lazily.

Comment: "I am NOT interested in actually creating an `Iterable<>` from an element" So what *are* you interested in? "if Java can handle enumerables/iterables as powerfully as C#" is unclear.

Comment: @Sweeper The C# code I wrote does not create an `IEnumerable<>` object; it merely transforms it lazily (it creates a "recipe" for how to get entries when needed). I want to know if Java has an equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`Collections.singleton()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-) or [`Collections.singletonList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-).

```
Collections.singleton(1);
Collections.singletonList("");
```

Returned collections are immutable in both cases, they are being backed only by the actual element. They are **not** real collections, in the sense, that they only allow iteration and other non modifying operations.

Or you can make the implementations of `Iterator` and `Iterable` yourself, although that would be reimplementing the above to some extent (jdk already provides similar/same functionality).

```
public class SingleElementIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

  private final T element;
  private boolean hasNext;

  public SingleElementIterator(T element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.hasNext = true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.hasNext;
  }

  @Override
  public T next() {
    if (this.hasNext) {
      this.hasNext = false;
      return this.element;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
  }
}
```

```
public class SingleElementIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  private final T element;

  public SingleElementIterable(T element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new SingleElementIterator<>(this.element);
  }
}
```

Example:

```
public class Temp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Iterable<String> iterable = new SingleElementIterable<>("abc");
    for (String string : iterable) {
      System.out.println(string);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But `Collections.singleton`/`Collections.singletonList` does create a `Set`/`List` object, right? Just like using `List<String> myIterable = new ArrayList<String>(); myIterable.add("foo");`? Your sample implementation also creates a new object on the heap. Isn't there a lazy way of doing it like in C# where no such collection is actually created on the heap?

Comment: As i wrote - `they are being backed only by the actual element.` Collections returned from `singleton...` methods are **not** real collections, you can think of them as wrappers around the element, which only allow you iteration and other non modifying operations. It's quite different from `List<String> myIterable = new ArrayList<String>(); myIterable.add("foo");`, which creates a real, full fledged list, backed by an array, allowing all operations.

Comment: My sample implementation also follows this idea. It's nothing more than a wrapper, allowing to iterate single element. And yes, it does create new object(not a collection in particular), but you can't escape from object creation. I'm not expert on c#, so don't take my word for it, but i believe that this yield return IEnumerable also creates an object(again, not a collection), just the syntax is shorter.